# Sourcetree fails to open Diffmerge for merge conflicts

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, diffmerge

Recently I had a fresh install of macOS. I've installed Sourctree and diffmerge and set diffmerge as the default merge tool. For some reason everytime when I select 'Resolve Conflicts -> Open External Merge Tool' sourcetree opens its waiting view and directly closes it.

My settings page in sourcetree:

[image]

This is how my root .gitconfig looks like when sourcetree configures diff merge for me:

```
[core]
    excludesfile = /Users/[username]/.gitignore_global
[user] 
    name = ---- -----
    email = -----@-----.--
[commit]
    template = /Users/[username]/.stCommitMsg
[credential]
    helper =  !/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -Ddebug=false -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true -jar /usr/local/Cellar/git-credential-manager/2.0.4/libexec/git-credential-manager-2.0.4.jar

[difftool "DiffMerge"]
[mergetool "DiffMerge"]
[diff]
    tool = diffmerge
[difftool "diffmerge"]
    cmd = /usr/local/bin/diffmerge \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
[merge]
    tool = diffmerge
[mergetool "diffmerge"]
    trustExitCode = true
    cmd = /usr/local/bin/diffmerge --merge --result=\"$MERGED\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\" \"$REMOTE\"
[difftool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = /Applications/DiffMerge.app/Contents/MacOS/DiffMerge/Contents/MacOS/DiffMerge --nosplash \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
path = 
[mergetool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = /Applications/DiffMerge.app/Contents/MacOS/DiffMerge/Contents/MacOS/DiffMerge --merge --result=\"$MERGED\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\" \"$REMOTE\"
    trustExitCode = true
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This happend to me when diffmerge was installed via the pkg install instead of the installer. This appearantly does not configure your bash to know the command `diffmerge` so than you have to set the path to the diffmerge (or update your bin config).

To solve this I manually configured Visual Diff Tool and Merge Tool (with as benefit that you can disable that annoying splash screen on launch everytime).

Settings page in sourcetree

[image]

**Diff**

Command: `/usr/local/bin/diffmerge`
Arguments `--nosplash "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"`

**Merge**

Command: `/usr/local/bin/diffmerge`
Arguments `--nosplash --merge --result="$MERGED" "$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$REMOTE"`

The --nosplash argument is optional but prevents the (in my opinion useless) pop up that you always have to close before you can start your work.

Git config file:

```
[core]
    excludesfile = /Users/[username]/.gitignore_global
[user]
    name = ---------
    email = ---------@------.--
[commit]
    template = /Users/[username]/.stCommitMsg
[credential]
    helper = !/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -Ddebug=false -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true -jar /usr/local/Cellar/git-credential-manager/2.0.4/libexec/git-credential-manager-2.0.4.jar

[difftool "DiffMerge"]
[mergetool "DiffMerge"]
[diff]
    tool = diffmerge
[difftool "diffmerge"]
    cmd = /usr/local/bin/diffmerge \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
[merge]
    tool = diffmerge
[mergetool "diffmerge"]
    trustExitCode = true
    cmd = /usr/local/bin/diffmerge --merge --result=\"$MERGED\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\" \"$REMOTE\"
[difftool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = /usr/local/bin/diffmerge --nosplash \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
    path = 
[mergetool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = /usr/local/bin/diffmerge --nosplash --merge --result=\"$MERGED\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\" \"$REMOTE\"
    trustExitCode = true
```

More info about diffmerge command line arguments:

Diff: https://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/webhelp/sec__clargs__diff.html

Merge: https://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/webhelp/sec__clargs__merge.html

Comment: Note that "Diff Command" may vary depending on where your diffmerge binary is located, in my case, it was: /Applications/DiffMerge.app/Contents/MacOS/DiffMerge

Comment: For me I could not use the --nosplash option.  It would popup with a "not found" error in "/var/folders".  But once I took out --nosplash for the custom diffmerge option, it then worked. Also, I did not quote the variables.

Comment: The issue I had was brought up here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76001320/971751
Removing --nosplash solved it.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this problem by following the instructions on the DiffMerge [Settings for OS X](https://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/webhelp/sec__git__mac.html) documentation page, which was:

First confirm that `/usr/local/bin/diffmerge` is present. 
If you used the PKG Installer, this was installed when /Applications/DiffMerge.app was installed. 
If you used the DMG file, refer to the instructions for installing the [Extras](https://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/webhelp/sec__inst__mac.html#sec__inst__mac__extras).

The following commands will update your `.gitconfig` to let GIT use DiffMerge:

```
$ git config --global diff.tool diffmerge
$ git config --global difftool.diffmerge.cmd
    "/usr/local/bin/diffmerge \"\$LOCAL\" \"\$REMOTE\""

$ git config --global merge.tool diffmerge
$ git config --global mergetool.diffmerge.trustExitCode true
$ git config --global mergetool.diffmerge.cmd 
    "/usr/local/bin/diffmerge --merge --result=\"\$MERGED\"
        \"\$LOCAL\" \"\$BASE\" \"\$REMOTE\""
```

I was then able to use DiffMerge by choosing the menu option in Sourcetree

[image: Sourcetree preference pane, showing the Diff tab, with DiffMerge selected for the Visual Diff Tool and Merge Tool options]

(*Optional*) You may want to add `--nosplash` to both commands, before other parameters, to avoid the splash screen (as also recommended by [@saren-inden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/461864/saren-inden)). i.e.;

```
$ git config --global diff.tool diffmerge
$ git config --global difftool.diffmerge.cmd
    "/usr/local/bin/diffmerge --nosplash \"\$LOCAL\" \"\$REMOTE\""

$ git config --global merge.tool diffmerge
$ git config --global mergetool.diffmerge.trustExitCode true
$ git config --global mergetool.diffmerge.cmd 
    "/usr/local/bin/diffmerge --nosplash --merge --result=\"\$MERGED\"
        \"\$LOCAL\" \"\$BASE\" \"\$REMOTE\""
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. DiffMerge is not launched either when I click **External Diff**.

The problem seems to be the path of DiffMerge in *.gitconfig* file:
`cmd = /Applications/DiffMerge.app/Contents/MacOS/DiffMerge/Contents/MacOS/DiffMerge ...`.

If you check the path `/Applications/DiffMerge.app/Contents/MacOS/DiffMerge`, it's actually not a directory but a file. It seems **SourceTree** adds `/Contents/MacOS/DiffMerge` twice on the path. I removed the duplicate part and the **External Diff** starts working.

Haven't tried merge.

Comment: If I do this and restart SourceTree, it re/instates the duplicate part. How to remove it for good_

Comment: @esbenr define custom diff tool as mentioned in Saren Inden's solution. Just copy correct cmd and arguments for diffMerge to sourcetree settings.