# Diff/Merge tool which allows editing files as well

Tags: diff, atlassian-sourcetree

I was using Tortoise GIT in windows OS which had TortoiseGitMerge editor where I can see the differences between 2 files, copy changes from left to right and vice versa, Edit the file directly while seeing the differences.

Is there a similar editor that I can download for MAC OS when using SourceTree because SourceTree sadly does not provide a good inbuilt editor by default.

I used kdiff but it is not allowing me to edit the files easily like the TortoiseGitMerge editor

Answer (score 0):

Try DiffMerge. This has all the 3 features that you mentioned
https://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53249871/6700081