# Diffmerge is unable to find Sourcetree files trying to resolve conflicts

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, diffmerge

[image]I have a new mac mini, M1 chip. When I try to resolve conflicts using diffmerge in sourcetree, diffmerge can't find the created temp files. Sourcetree creates the files, they're out there and diffmerge has the correct filenames and paths, but I'm getting this error message.

Has anyone experienced this problem?

I've tried to give full disk access to sourcetree and diffmerge. I think there must be some kind of problem with permissions or the temp folders being hidden from diffmerge or something.

I've tried to follow the instructions in [Sourcetree fails to open Diffmerge for merge conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249870/sourcetree-fails-to-open-diffmerge-for-merge-conflicts) but I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this as well. Found the option recommended here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53249871/971751

Setting custom diffmerge path and arguments worked for me except one key difference.  If I used the --nosplash argument I would get the diffmerge popup error you received.  Try taking out the --nosplash if you use the custom option.

Also, I did not quote the arguments like advised and it's working. So my merge command arguments look like:

```
--merge --result=$MERGED $LOCAL $BASE $REMOTE
```

[image]